# Gulp compiling multiple css files into one

Tags: html, css, gulp

I have two files, `main.css` and `_vars.css` and i'm using PostCSS. I'm still learning the different plugins and setup with PostCSS however, i'm also fairly new to Gulp so i'm having an issue with compiling my css files.

I want to read, both `main.css` and `_vars.css` then compile them into

`./bundle/stylecss/` into a file called `main.css`.

```
  gulp.task('css', function () {
     return gulp.src('./postcss/**/*.css')
        // .pipe(postcss([ vars({ variables: colors }) ]))
        .pipe(postcss([ require('postcss-simple-vars')({ silent: true }) ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./bundle/stylescss/main.css'));
});
```

My gulp file is above, but when I run my gulpfile it I get [image]

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `gulp.dest()` is for the folder, not the file itself (think using multiple files). Remove `main.css` from the `dest` bit and see what gets saved out. If you need to rename a file, you can use plugins like *gulp-rename*

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a gulp plugin or a postcss plugin to do that.

The gulp plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat

The postcss plugin: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import

I'd prefer the postcss plugin because it's less magic, but either will do the job :)